# Get HTML content from XML tree with Dom in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I have an Xml like this:

```
  <root>
    <item>
    <content type="HTML">
       <![CDATA[<html>
        <head></head>
        <body>something goes there</body>
       </html>]]>
    </content>         
   </item>
   <item>
    <content type="Text">
      Something goes there
    </content>         
   </item>
  </root>
```

With content is text type, I can get with *node.getTextContent()*.
The problem is I want to get all the Html content from Xml tree. So the result I want to get is the string:

```
  "<html><head></head><body>some thing goes there</body></html>"
```

How can I do that with Document (DOM) in Android?
**Note**: Because I have to edit some xml content, so I can't use SAX.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See DOM parser Example:

http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using.html

A xml may have different type of nodes, see possible Node Types:
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp

You have various methods in android to parse Xml through DOM parser, methods useful are following:

```
getElementsByTagName - Return Array of Nodes by Tag Name specified.
getChildNodes - retervies the list of childs of Node
getAttributes()- retrieves attributes of a Node
getFirstChild- returns first child node of Node Object
getNodeName, getNodeType, getNodeValue- returns corresponding values from Node
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already read these APIs. But it is not easy to solve my problem because I need not only node name and value, but also the '<,>' tag. So, the question is HOW?